# Get value from external file

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a file called `version.h` that among other things contains the following line:

```
#define VERSION 0.4.2-b
```

Now, on the Sphinx documentation for this piece of software, I'd like to display this value in one of the `.rst` files.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See the [`literalinclude`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/code.html#includes) directive.

In your case:

```
.. literalinclude:: version.h
    :language: c
```

For the proper syntax highlighting, you can change the [Pygments lexer](http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/#lexers-for-c-c-languages) by specifying the language attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This allowed me to get the complete line of code that contains the define that I need. However, it doesn't provide a way to get the value of `VERSION` allone, which is what I intended.

Comment: That is not what you asked in your question, so you should update it accordingly. Sphinx does not parse C files. You must declare variables separately in the `conf.py` file and use replacements. See an [example in Pyramid](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/docs/conf.py#L104-L108), which gets picked up in most themes.